# App stops to execute on: openDocumentWithContentsOfURL:display:error:

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

The app stops to execute on  `openDocumentWithContentsOfURL:display:error:`

I've also tried the newest method: `openDocumentWithContentsOfURL:display:completionHandler:`
without success.

There is no error message, this is the last debug step I can't make.
I can't print the error in the next line.

What could be the reason?

```
if ([newDocument writeSafelyToURL:[save URL] ofType:[newDocument databaseName] forSaveOperation:NSSaveAsOperation error:nil]) {
            NSDocumentController *controller = [NSDocumentController sharedDocumentController];

            CBDebug(@"About to open document");

            NSError * error = nil;
            [controller openDocumentWithContentsOfURL:[save URL] display:YES error:&error];
            CBDebug(@"error %@", error);
```

Comment: did you check if your URL is incorrect, also it might get stuck on some recursion or deadlock.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya What is weird, is that the URL always worked. I get the URL from the NSSavePanel (I've added the code to the question). However, it seems that it doesn't consider anymore the path as a file, but a directory (ps. the same code worked before the project upgrading to Xcode5).

Comment: @AnoopVaidya I've tried to feed openDocumentWithContentsOfURL with another hardcoded URL and it actually works. So it seems that it can't open a file that has just being created.

Comment: Ohhh. Now I got the issue. This is happening due to *timing* issue. You need to *wait* before reading the file, as I mentioned a #deadlock#. put some dummy loop or wait for few seconds and try again.

Comment: How about if you call it on the next run loop cycle using `dispatch_after()`?

Comment: @AnoopVaidya I've used a timer with 1 second delay: same issue. But what's really strange is that the same code worked in the past. Something change upgrading the project from Xcode3 to Xcode5.

Comment: @trojanfoe I'm now using dispatch_after (1 sec delay): it is the same. The code runs until openDocumentWithContentsOfURL, afterwords it stops. I can't debug further, it is the last step.

Comment: I've just tried to run my previous app version on the same machine and it works. Same code. Maybe some preferences in the project? File privileges ?

Comment: no sure but there might be some API change through compiler that makes it run on different thread...so before writing the file completely it starts reading it!!!

Comment: @AnoopVaidya I see, what do you suggest, to run it on the main thread?

Comment: @AnoopVaidya No... no success: I'm now running the content of the above "if statement" with [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(continueNewDocument:) withObject:url waitUntilDone:YES];

Comment: But then how do you usually immediately open a document you just created?

Comment: It seems strange to me that you have the document in memory already and all you really need to do is add it to the document controller (if it's not already added) and display its windows.  I don't see why you need to get the document controller to "open" an already-open document.  How about `[controller addDocument:newDocument]; [newDocument makeWindowControllers]; [newDocument showWindows];`?

Comment: @trojanfoe OK, that could be the solution. It works beside that the new document is not associated with the file just created. I need to  specify again the url to save it. You know how could I set its file location instead?

Comment: That sounds like a failing in `writeSafelyToURL`.  It should be saving that URL with `self.fileURL = url;` somewhere.

Comment: @trojanfoe fileURL is currently nil, after calling writeSafelyToURL:ofType:forSaveOperation: but the file is correctly created on hard disk.

Comment: It still needs to "record" the new URL in `[NSDocument fileURL]` when the save succeeds (i.e. you can write to the URL but you need to tell the document it is now using that URL).

Comment: I've manually set it. newDocument.fileURL = [save URL]; and everything works fine now. I will post the updated code in the question.. just to be sure is good enough.

Comment: That should be inside `writeSafelyToURL:ofType:forSaveOperation:` and you shouldn't have to set it from outside.  You would also want to record the `fileType` as well.  (ALSO you have the order wrong in your "NEW CODE" - save first and only open it if save succeeds)

Comment: @trojanfoe I've updated the code in the question as you suggested. If you add an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

```
if ([newDocument writeSafelyToURL:[save URL] ofType:[newDocument databaseName] forSaveOperation:NSSaveAsOperation error:nil]) {
        newDocument.fileURL = [save URL];

        NSDocumentController *controller = [NSDocumentController sharedDocumentController];
        [controller addDocument:newDocument];
        [newDocument makeWindowControllers];
        [newDocument showWindows];
}
```